# jQuery :not/.not filter not behaving properly

Tags: jquery

So i was trying to append some code to all my images(for a rollover) in a certain portion of my document via javascript (primarily for graceful degredation purposes)etc and so

after noticing my function not work...i wrote a super small function to test it and no good. In this example, what im trying to do is alert an images alt tag but **not** a specific button div. Essentially, apply said function to all images in a parent div (portSecW) and not the close buttons image/div.

so for the sake of this example, heres some HTML(pseudo):

```
<div id="portSecW">
  <img src="X" alt="something here"></img>
  <img src="a" alt="something here"></img>
  <img src="b" alt="something here"></img>
  <div class="closeXbtn"><img src="g" alt="something here"></img></div>
</div>
```

Here is what ive tried.

```
$('#portSecW img:not(".closeXbtn")').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});
```

Ive also gone about it like this

```
$('#portSecW img').not('.closeXbtn').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});
```

ive also tried like this but doesnt work (so im assuming that although i get no errors, its not constructed properly because the alert function doesnt fire.)

```
$('#portSecW img.not(".closeXbtn")').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});
```

So not sure what im doing wrong.

Thanks in advanced.

**NOTE:** Just incase anyone is looking, the marked ""accepted answer" worked for me but upon further digging. all of my tries above worked, the problem was i wasnt precise enough with how i traversed the DOM. So all of these do the same thing and work. here are the changes i made and again, these all worked.

```
$('#portSecW a').children('img').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});

$('#portSecW img').not(".closeXbtn img").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});

$('#portSecW img:not(".closeXbtn img")').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});
```

Thanks Everyone for your help

Comment: .closeXbtn is a typo? otherwise that's one of your problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.children()`:

```
$('#portSecW').children('img').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});
```

The `.children()` method allows us to search through the children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` **only travels a single level down the DOM tree**.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotes around the class eg:

```
$('#portSecW img:not(.closeXbtn)').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
  return false;
});
```

Failing that you could do something like:

```
$('#portSecW img').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('closeXbtn')))  { /* do something */ }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#portSecW img').not(".closeXbtn img").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});
```

OR

```
$('#portSecW > img').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});
```

Second one it more accurate. That will bind click event to direct children of `portSecW`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help you:

```
$('#portSecW > img').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});
```

... it will only select direct IMG descendants of the main div, omitting the one within closeXbtn div.

However, if you need to keep your functionality, maybe this might be of a better use:

```
$('#portSecW img:not(:parent(.closeXbtn))').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("alt")); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your "not"and simply edit this

```
$('#portSecW img').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('closeXbtn'))
    //Do some play
})
```

Comment: Because you are selecting images only but not a div in that "portSecw" div..but if you want to select a div instead of image then you need to pass the "not"query